# What is the relationship between __getattr__ and getattr?

Tags: python, getattr

I know this code is right:

```
class A:   
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'  
    def method(self):   
        print "method print"  

a = A()   
print getattr(a, 'a', 'default')   
print getattr(a, 'b', 'default')  
print getattr(a, 'method', 'default') 
getattr(a, 'method', 'default')()
```

And this is wrong:

```
# will __getattr__ affect the getattr?

class a(object):
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return 'xxx'

print getattr(a)
```

This is also wrong:

```
a={'aa':'aaaa'}
print getattr(a,'aa')
```

Where should we use `__getattr__` and `getattr`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the difference between \_\_getattr\_\_ and \_\_getattribute\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295678/understanding-the-difference-between-getattr-and-getattribute)

Comment: @Trilarion that is not a proper duplicate for this question

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Alex's answer was good, but providing you with a sample code since you asked for it :)

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return "You asked for %s, but I'm giving you default" % attribute


>>> bar = foo()
>>> bar.a
'a'
>>> bar.b
"You asked for b, but I'm giving you default"
>>> getattr(bar, "a")
'a'
>>> getattr(bar, "b")
"You asked for b, but I'm giving you default"
```

So in short answer is

You use

`__getattr__` to **define** how to handle attributes that are **not found**

and

`getattr` to **get** the **attributes**

Comment: Watch out if you use `__getattr__` because it breaks the `copy` built in module unless you also implement `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` for your class. Took me some time to trace this bug... On 2.7 anyways

Answer (score 40):

`getattr` is a built-in function taking (at least) two arguments: the object from which you're getting the attribute, and the string name of the attribute.

If the string name is a constant, say `'foo'`, `getattr(obj, 'foo')` is **exactly the same thing** as `obj.foo`.

So, the main use case for the built-in function `getattr` is when you don't have the attribute name as a constant, but rather as a variable. A second important use case is when you pass it three arguments, rather than just two: in that case, if the attribute is absent from the object, `getattr` returns the third, "default", argument, rather than raising an exception.

`__getattr__` is a special method, defined in a class, that gets invoked when some attribute of an instance of that class is requested, and other normal ways to supply that attribute (via the instance's `__dict__`, slots, properties, and so on) all failed.  You can define it, for example, when you want to delegate otherwise-undefined attribute lookups to other objects.

So your second example is wrong because the builtin `getattr` can **never** be called with a single argument.

The third one fails because the dictionary you're trying to "get an attribute" from does not have that attribute -- it has **items**, which are totally disjoint from attributes of course.

Comment: While your answer is excellent, @zjm1126 wanted a code sample because his english is not so good.

Answer (score 19):

`__getattr__()` is a special method function that you can define.  When a member lookup fails, this function will be called.

`getattr()` is a function you can call to attempt a member lookup.  If the lookup succeeds, you get the member (perhaps a method function object, or perhaps a data attribute object).  `getattr()` can also return a default in the case the lookup fails.

If you declare a `__getattr__()` member function, you can make it succeed sometimes, or you can make it succeed every time.

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return "I pretend I have an attribute called '%s'" % name

a = A()

print a.foo # prints "I pretend I have an attribute called 'foo'"
```

Python also has `__getattribute__()` which is *always* called on every lookup.  It is very dangerous because it can make it impossible to access members normally.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.v = value
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return "I pretend I have an attribute called '%s'" % name

a = A(42)

print a.v # prints "I pretend I have an attribute called 'v'"
print a.__dict__["v"] # prints "I pretend I have an attribute called '__dict__'"
```

Oops, it is now impossible to access a.v!

Comment: +1 for mentioning __getattribute__ which I guess the question was actually about.

Comment: Nice and simple explanation of __getattribute__ that had always seemed unclear to me.