# Understanding the difference between __getattr__ and __getattribute__

Tags: python, oop, getattr, getattribute

I am trying to understand the difference between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`, however, I am failing at it.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278104/3798217) to the Stack Overflow question *[Difference between `__getattr__` vs `__getattribute__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3278077/3798217)* says:

> `__getattribute__` is invoked before looking at the actual attributes on
>   the object, and so can be tricky to
>   implement correctly. You can end up in
>   infinite recursions very easily.

I have absolutely no idea what that means.

Then it goes on to say:

> You almost certainly want `__getattr__`.

Why?

I read that if `__getattribute__` fails, `__getattr__` is called. So why are there two different methods doing the same thing? If my code implements the new style classes, what should I use?

I am looking for some code examples to clear this question. I have Googled to best of my ability, but the answers that I found don't discuss the problem thoroughly.

If there is any documentation, I am ready to read that.

Comment: if it helps, from the docs "In order to avoid infinite recursion in this method, its implementation should always call the base class method with the same name to access any attributes it needs, for example, object.__getattribute__(self, name)." [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_\_getattr\_\_ vs \_\_getattribute\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute)

Answer (score 387, accepted):

## Some basics first.

With objects, you need to deal with their attributes. Ordinarily, we do `instance.attribute`.  Sometimes we need more control (when we do not know the name of the attribute in advance).

For example, `instance.attribute` would become `getattr(instance, attribute_name)`.  Using this model, we can get the attribute by supplying the *attribute_name* as a string.

## Use of `__getattr__`

You can also tell a class how to deal with attributes which it doesn't explicitly manage and do that via `__getattr__` method.

Python will call this method whenever you request an attribute that hasn't already been defined, so you can define what to do with it.

A classic use case:

```
class A(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
       return self[name]
a = A()
# Now a.somekey will give a['somekey']
```

## Caveats and use of `__getattribute__`

If you need to catch every attribute *regardless whether it exists or not*, use `__getattribute__` instead.  The difference is that `__getattr__` only gets called for attributes that don't actually exist.  If you set an attribute directly, referencing that attribute will retrieve it without calling `__getattr__`.

`__getattribute__` is called all the times.

Comment: " For example, instance.attribute would become `getattr(instance, attribute_name)`. " . Shouldn't it be `__getattribute__(instance, attribute_name)` ?

Comment: @Md.AbuNafeeIbnaZahid `getattr` is a built-in function. `getattr(foo, 'bar')` is equivalent to `foo.bar`.

Comment: worth noting that `__getattr__` only gets called if it's defined, as it's not inherited from `object`

Answer (score 122):

`__getattribute__` is called whenever an attribute access occurs.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = 1

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            return self.__dict__[attr]
        except KeyError:
            return 'default'
f = Foo(1)
f.a
```

This will cause infinite recursion. The culprit here is the line `return self.__dict__[attr]`. Let's pretend (It's close enough to the truth) that all attributes are stored in `self.__dict__` and available by their name. The line

```
f.a
```

attempts to access the `a` attribute of `f`. This calls `f.__getattribute__('a')`. `__getattribute__` then tries to load `self.__dict__`. `__dict__` is an attribute of `self == f` and so python calls `f.__getattribute__('__dict__')` which again tries to access the attribute `'__dict__`'. This is infinite recursion.

If `__getattr__` had been used instead then

1. It never would have run because `f` has an `a` attribute.
2. If it had run, (let's say that you asked for `f.b`) then it would not have been called to find `__dict__` because it's already there and `__getattr__` is invoked only if *all other methods of finding the attribute have failed*.

The 'correct' way to write the above class using `__getattribute__` is

```
class Foo(object):
    # Same __init__

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        return super().__getattribute__(attr)
```

`super().__getattribute__(attr)` binds the `__getattribute__` method of the 'nearest' superclass (formally, the next class in the class's Method Resolution Order, or MRO) to the current object `self` and then calls it and lets that do the work.

All of this trouble is avoided by using `__getattr__` which lets Python *do it's normal thing* until an attribute isn't found. At that point, Python hands control over to your `__getattr__` method and lets it come up with something.

It's also worth noting that you can run into infinite recursion with `__getattr__`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.attr
```

I'll leave that one as an exercise.

Comment: When you call `super(Foo, self)`, is that right that you are explicitly grabbing the nearest parent class of `Foo` and then passing in instance `self` as the second argument? Could you have done `super()` instead of `super(Foo, self)` since Python 3 uses Method Resolution Order to implicitly figure out `self`'s most relevant parent class (which is very useful when using multiple inheritance) ??

Comment: @E.Kaufman, bro the answer was posted on 2010, over ten years by the time you made such an ignorant comment.

Comment: Edited the answer to follow PEP 3135; Use `super()` instead of the `super(Foo, self)`.

Answer (score 71):

I think the other answers have done a great job of explaining the difference between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`, but one thing that might not be clear is why you would want to use `__getattribute__`.  The cool thing about `__getattribute__` is that it essentially allows you to overload the dot when accessing a class.  This allows you to customize how attributes are accessed at a low level.  For instance, suppose I want to define a class where all methods that only take a self argument are treated as properties:

```
# prop.py
import inspect

class PropClass(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        val = super().__getattribute__(attr)
        if callable(val):
            argcount = len(inspect.getargspec(val).args)
            # Account for self
            if argcount == 1:
                return val()
            else:
                return val
        else:
            return val
```

And from the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> import prop
>>> class A(prop.PropClass):
...     def f(self):
...             return 1
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f
1
```

Of course this is a silly example and you probably wouldn't ever want to do this, but it shows you the power you can get from overriding `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 19):

I have gone through other's excellent explanation. However, I found a simple answer from this blog [Python Magic Methods and `__getattr__`](https://blog.rmotr.com/python-magic-methods-and-getattr-75cf896b3f88). All the following are from there.

Using the `__getattr__` magic method, we can intercept that inexistent attribute lookup and do something so it doesn’t fail:

```
class Dummy(object):

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return attr.upper()

d = Dummy()
d.does_not_exist # 'DOES_NOT_EXIST'
d.what_about_this_one  # 'WHAT_ABOUT_THIS_ONE'
```

But if the attribute does exist, `__getattr__` won’t be invoked:

```
class Dummy(object):

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return attr.upper()

d = Dummy()
d.value = "Python"
print(d.value)  # "Python"
```

`__getattribute__` is similar to `__getattr__`, with the important difference that `__getattribute__` will intercept **EVERY** attribute lookup, doesn’t matter if the attribute exists or not.

```
class Dummy(object):

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        return 'YOU SEE ME?'

d = Dummy()
d.value = "Python"
print(d.value)  # "YOU SEE ME?"
```

In that example, the `d` object already has an attribute value. But when we try to access it, we don’t get the original expected value (“Python”); we’re just getting whatever `__getattribute__` returned. It means that we’ve virtually lost the value attribute; it has become “unreachable”.