# How does extending classes (Monkey Patching) work in Python?

Tags: python, oop, object, monkeypatching

```
class Foo(object):
  pass

foo = Foo()
def bar(self):
  print 'bar'

Foo.bar = bar
foo.bar() #bar
```

Coming from JavaScript, if a "class" prototype was augmented with a certain attribute. It is known that all instances of that "class" would have that attribute in its prototype chain, hence no modifications has to be done on any of its instances or "sub-classes".

In that sense, how can a Class-based language like Python achieve Monkey patching?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The real question is, how can it not? In Python, classes are first-class objects in their own right. Attribute access on instances of a class is resolved by looking up attributes on the instance, and then the class, and then the parent classes (in the method resolution order.) These lookups are all done at runtime (as is everything in Python.) If you add an attribute to a class after you create an instance, the instance will still "see" the new attribute, simply because nothing prevents it.

In other words, it works because Python doesn't cache attributes (unless your code does), because it doesn't use negative caching or shadowclasses or any of the optimization techniques that would inhibit it (or, when Python implementations do, they take into account the class might change) and because everything is runtime.

Comment: I thought this couldn't be done and was a differentiator with Ruby.

Comment: So method dispatch in dynamic class-based languages works in an identical way to prototype-based languages?

Comment: "So method dispatch... works in an identical way... ?" It depends on how much you want to generalize. See my answer for the specifics of "how it works" specifically for Python. Other dynamic class-based languages don't necessarily do quite the same thing. Other prototype-based languages don't necessarily do exactly what Javascript does, either, FWIW.

Comment: rather than "it's all done on runtime", it's more useful to say that all name resolution are done at "access time", as opposed to "definition time" or "instantiation time".

Answer (score 10):

I just read through a bunch of documentation, and as far as I can tell, the *whole story* of how `foo.bar` is resolved, is as follows:

- Can we find `foo.__getattribute__` by the following process? If so, use the result of `foo.__getattribute__('bar')`.

  - (Looking up `__getattribute__` will not cause infinite recursion, but the implementation of it might.)
  - (In reality, we will always find `__getattribute__` in new-style objects, as a default implementation is provided in `object` - but that implementation is of the following process. ;) )
  - (If we define a `__getattribute__` method in `Foo`, and access `foo.__getattribute__`, `foo.__getattribute__('__getattribute__')` **will** be called! But this does **not** imply infinite recursion - *if you are careful* ;) )
- Is `bar` a "special" name for an attribute provided by the Python runtime (e.g. `__dict__`, `__class__`, `__bases__`, `__mro__`)? If so, use that. (As far as I can tell, `__getattribute__` falls into this category, which avoids infinite recursion.)
- Is `bar` in the `foo.__dict__` dict? If so, use `foo.__dict__['bar']`.
- Does `foo.__mro__` exist (i.e., is `foo` actually a class)? If so,

  - For each base-class `base` in `foo.__mro__`[1:]:

    - (Note that the first one will be `foo` itself, which we already searched.)
    - Is `bar` in `base.__dict__`? If so:

      - Let `x` be `base.__dict__['bar']`.
      - Can we find (again, recursively, but it won't cause a problem) `x.__get__`?

        - If so, use `x.__get__(foo, foo.__class__)`.
        - (Note that the function `bar` is, itself, an object, and the Python compiler automatically gives functions a `__get__` attribute which is designed to be used this way.)
        - Otherwise, use `x`.
- For each base-class `base` of `foo.__class__.__mro__`:

  - (Note that this recursion is not a problem: those attributes should always exist, and fall into the "provided by the Python runtime" case. `foo.__class__.__mro__[0]` will always be `foo.__class__`, i.e. `Foo` in our example.)
  - (Note that we do this even if `foo.__mro__` exists. This is because classes have a class, too: its name is `type`, and it provides, among other things, the method used to calculate `__mro__` attributes in the first place.)
  - Is `bar` in `base.__dict__`? If so:

    - Let `x` be `base.__dict__['bar']`.
    - Can we find (again, recursively, but it won't cause a problem) `x.__get__`?

      - If so, use `x.__get__(foo, foo.__class__)`.
      - (Note that the function `bar` is, itself, an object, and the Python compiler automatically gives functions a `__get__` attribute which is designed to be used this way.)
      - Otherwise, use `x`.
- If we **still** haven't found something to use: can we find `foo.__getattr__` by the preceding process? If so, use the result of `foo.__getattr__('bar')`.
- If **everything** failed, `raise AttributeError`.

`bar.__get__` is not really a function - it's a "method-wrapper" - but you can imagine it being implemented vaguely like this:

```
# Somewhere in the Python internals
class __method_wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, obj, cls):
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        # Except it actually returns a "bound method" object
        # that uses cls for its __repr__
    # and there is a __repr__ for the method_wrapper that I *think*
    # uses the hashcode of the underlying function, rather than of itself,
    # but I'm not sure.

# Automatically done after compiling bar
bar.__get__ = __method_wrapper(bar)
```

The "binding" that happens within the `__get__` automatically attached to `bar` (called a *descriptor*), by the way, is more or less the reason why you have to specify `self` parameters explicitly for Python methods. In Javascript, `this` itself is magical; in Python, it is merely the process of binding things to `self` that is magical. ;)

And yes, you **can** explicitly set a `__get__` method on your own objects and have it do special things when you set a class attribute to an instance of the object and then access it from an instance of that other class. Python is **extremely** reflective. :) But if you want to learn how to do that, and get a really full understanding of the situation, you [have a lot](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#new-attribute-access) of reading [to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295678/understanding-the-difference-between-getattr-and-getattribute). ;)

Comment: Thanks @karl thats very helpful, and somewhat confusing :)