# How python adds atributes to class in this code?

Tags: python

How python adds attributes val1 and val2 to class. Does python internally invoke something like b1.__shared_state['val1'] = 'Jaga Gola!!!'?

```
# Borg (monostate pattern) lets a class have as many instances as one likes,
# but ensures that they all share the same state


class Borg:
    __shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state



b1 = Borg()
b2 = Borg()

print(b1 == b2)
b1.val1 = 'Jaga Gola!!!'
b1.val2 = 'BOOOM!!!'
print(b2.val1, b1.val2)
```

And why if I delete `_shared_state and self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state` I can't add attribute to class and get error: AttributeError: 'Borg' object has no attribute 'val1'?

```
class Borg:

    def __init__(self):
        pass



b1 = Borg()
b2 = Borg()

print(b1 == b2)
b1.val1 = 'Jaga Gola!!!'
b1.val2 = 'BOOOM!!!'
print(b2.val1, b1.val2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does extending classes (Monkey Patching) work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286006/how-does-extending-classes-monkey-patching-work-in-python)

Comment: For your second question: because without the explicit shared state, `b1` and `b2` *don't share state*, so `b2.val1` doesn't exist.

Comment: *"Does python internally invoke something like `b1.__shared_state['val1'] = 'Jaga Gola!!!'`?"* - yes. Instance attributes are stored in `__dict__`.

Comment: OK, I did not see, that I use b2.val1 instead of b1.val1. I check and it works with this change.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
class Borg:
    __shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
```

- The `__shared_state = {}` line occurs at class level, so it is added once to the class `Borg`, not to every individual object of type `Borg`. It is the same as writing `Borg.__shared_state = {}` afterwards.
- The `self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state` is confusing because it uses `self.` twice but has very different effects:

  - When **assigning to** `self.something`, that `something` is set in the object `self`. No surprise there.
  - But when **reading from** `self.something`, first `something` is looked for in the `self` object, and if it's not found there then it's looked for in the object's class. That mind sound weird but you actually use that all the time: that's how methods normally work. For example, in `s = "foo"; b = s.startswith("f")`, the object `s` doesn't have an attribute `startswith`, but its class `str` does and that's what is used when you call the method.

This line:

```
b1.val1 = 'Jaga Gola!!!'
```

Ends up translating to:

```
b1.__dict__['val1'] = 'Jaga Gola!!!'
```

But we know that `b1.__dict__` is equal to `Borg.__shared_state`, so it's assigned to that. Then:

```
print(b2.val1, ...
```

translates to:

```
print(b2.__dict__['val1'])
```

and again we know that  `b2.__dict__` is equal to the **same** `Borg.__shared_state` so `val1` is found.

If you remove the stuff about `__shared_state` at the beginning then `b1` and `b2` get their own `__dict__` objects so putting `val1` into the dict of `b1` has no effect on `b2`, and that's how you get the error you mentioned.

---

This is all fine for playing around with to understand what's happening, but you should realise that this code isn't guaranteed to work and might break e.g. in a future version of Python or another implementation such as PyPy. The [Python documentation for `__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes) describes it as a "read-only attribute" so you shouldn't be assigning to it at all. Don't do this in code that anybody else might run!

In fact, the idea that `a.foo` is just `a.__dict__['foo']` is a huge simplification. For a start, we already encountered that sometimes it's followed by `a.__class__.__dict__['foo']` when reading. Another example is that `a.__dict__` is clearly not `a.__dict__['__dict__']`, otherwise how would it ever it end!? The process is somewhat complicated and documented in [the Data Model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access).

The supported way to get this behaviour is to use the special `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` methods (also described in those Data Model docs), like this:

```
class Borg:
    __shared_state = {}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return Borg.__shared_state[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        Borg.__shared_state[name] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an interesting thing what you are doing there, and its based on mutability:

The initial `__shared_state` that you declared is created before any of your code is execute. That dictionary is known as Class Attribute, because it is linked to the class, not an instance (does not use `self` for declaration). This means that `__shared_state` is shared between `b1` and `b2` because it is created before them, and since it is a `dict`, it is mutable.

### What does it mean that it is mutable?

It means that one dictionary assigned to two different instances, will reference to same memory address, and even if we change the dicttonary, the memory address will remain the same. Here is a probe:

```py
class Example:

    __shared_state = {1: 1}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        print(self.__shared_state)

ex1 = Example()
ex2 = Example()

print(id(ex1.__dict__), id(ex2.__dict__))

# Prints
# {1: 1}
# {1: 1}
# 140704387518944 140704387518944
```

Notice how they have the same id? That's because they are refering to the same object, and since the `dictionary` type is mutable, altering the dictionary in one object, means that you are changing it for both, because they are the same:

```py
# Executing this
ex1.val1 = 2
# Equals this
ex1.__dict__['val1'] = 2
# Which also equals this
Example.__shared_state['val1'] = 2
```

This does not happen with integers, which are **immutable**:

```py
class Example:

    __shared_state = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = self.__shared_state
        print(self.__shared_state)

ex1 = Example()
ex2 = Example()

ex2.a = 3

print(id(ex1.a), id(ex2.a))
# Prints
# 2
# 2
# 9302176 9302208
# Notice that once we change ex2.a, its ID changes!
```

When you delete your `__shared_state`, the moment you assign `b1.val1 = 'Jaga Gola!!!'` and `b1.val2 = 'BOOOM!!!'`, it is only assigning to the dictionary from `b1`, thats why when you try to print `b2.val1` and `b2.val2` it raises an Error.

Comment: This is a nice answer but you are mixing in discussion about mutibility which is not relevant here. You say "What does it mean to be mutable?" and the next sentence is "It means that both instances of your class reference the same dictionary". That is NOT what mutable means: you can have immutable state that is shared and mutable state that isn't shared, so mutability really has nothing to do with state being shared.