# Automatically execute code in front of module methods

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) module, but the question is much more generic.

Is there a way to automatically execute code before calling methods from imported modules?

This would make writing code easier for me. At the moment I worry about hammering friendly webservices, so unless I can find an answer, I'll have to implement my own controls.

---

I thought by doing this:

```
import requests as requests2
```

...then at some point further on in the code, define a `requests()` function, with special arguments or some magical undiscovered syntax.  After running its own code, the special sauce would forward method calls to the real module aliased to `requests2`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like adding decorators to every function in another module? You could emulate that with a class:

```
class RequestsProxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.special_sauce_decorator = special_sauce_indeed()
        self._requests = __import__("requests")

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        val = getattr(self._requests, attrname) 
        if callable(val):
            return self.special_sauce_decorator(val)
        return val
```

Example usage:

```
>>> def special_sauce_indeed():
        def decorator(f):
                def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
                        print 'wrapped'
                        return f(*args, **kwargs)
                return wrapped
        return decorator

>>> class OsProxy(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.special_sauce_decorator = special_sauce_indeed()
            self._requests = __import__("os")

        def __getattr__(self, attrname):
            val = getattr(self._requests, attrname)
            if callable(val):
                return self.special_sauce_decorator(val)
            return val


>>> os = OsProxy()
>>> os.listdir(".")
wrapped
['DLLs', 'Doc', 'faiojerf.py', 'func_counter_test.py', 'include', 'inet_time.py', 'kcol.py', 'Lib', 'libs', 'LICENSE.txt', 'memoize_test.py', 'minpy.py', 'NEWS.txt', 'numpy-wininst.log', 'paren_test.py', 'PIL-wininst.log', 'psycopg2-wininst.log', 'python.exe', 'pythonw.exe', 'pywin32-wininst.log', 'README.txt', 'Removenumpy.exe', 'RemovePIL.exe', 'Removepsycopg2.exe', 'Removepywin32.exe', 'Removescipy.exe', 'Removesetuptools.exe', 'scipy-wininst.log', 'Scripts', 'setuptools-wininst.log', 'slots.py', 'so1.py', 'staticvar.py', 'summing.py', 'taojiwjiot.,py', 'tcl', 'templol.py', 'test.py', 'thunkify_test.py', 'TicketNumberGenerator.py', 'Tools', 'w9xpopen.exe', 'wordcount.py']
```

Comment: Neato! I wouldn't do all of the exception checking -- 'getattr' will raise the default exception anyway (and arguably `special_sauce_decorator` should handle the case of non-callables). EAFP and all that =)

Comment: European Association of Fish Pathologists? oh, [gotcha](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp). good point

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea. Make a proxy for 'requests' that does whatever it wants to do then forwards the method call to the actual `requests` module. For example

```
class RequestProxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import requests as _requests
        self._requests = _requests

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        run_custom_code()
        return getattr(self._requests, attr)

requests = RequestProxy()
```

Comment: One thing, you have `__getattribute__`, whereas Claudiu has `__getattr__`. I didn't mention a python version...apologies.

Comment: @Jon it's not a Python version thing -- [they do different things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295678/understanding-the-difference-between-getattr-and-getattribute) =)

Comment: "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" - I shamefully can't get this to work. py 2.6.6, requests v0.13.6

Comment: Oops, sorry, of course that would happen -- my bad! The problem is that `getattr` calls `__getattribute__`. You want Claudiu's `__getattr__`.