# how to avoid class having a __dict__

Tags: python-3.x

I noticed many built-in classes do not have a `__dict__` and even classes in modules such as `numpy` do not have `__dict__` defined as they had been defined in C.

I want to define `__getattr__`, but I'm worried about a recursive loop creeping into the (long) code of one of my class (e.g. see the second reply [Understanding the difference between __getattr__ and __getattribute__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295678/understanding-the-difference-between-getattr-and-getattribute)).

Is there a way I can disable creation of `__dict__`? Do I need to use `__slots__` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having a `__dict__` will not prevent you from writing an infinite recursive loop.

And yes, defining `__slots__` will prevent the creation of a `__dict__`.