# python object style access for dictionaries ; cant figure it out

Tags: python, getattr, setattr

```
class ObjectDict(dict):
    """ allows object style access for dictionaries """

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            return self[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError('No such attribute: %s' % name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            del self[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError('No such attribute: %s' % name)
```

can someone explain this code for me ? I'm just a python beginner.

Comment: What specifically do you need help understanding? This is far too broad.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295678/understanding-the-difference-between-getattr-and-getattribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`__getattr__`** is for when you want to *get* a data.

**`__setattr__`** is for when you want to *set* a data.

**`__delattr__`** is for when you want to *del* a data.

Now, the methods should be quite clear.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    # if the key exists... return it.
    if name in self:
        return self[name]
    # if not : raise an error.
    else:
        raise AttributeError('No such attribute: %s' % name)

def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    # set VALUE as value, with NAME as key in the dict.
    self[name] = value

def __delattr__(self, name):
    # if the key "name" exists in the dictionnary... delete it
    if name in self:
        del self[name]
    # else, it doesnt exist, so cant delete it.
    else:
        raise AttributeError('No such attribute: %s' % name)
```

Comment: Thanks really helpful

Comment: I invite you to accept the answer if you found it the most helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 2):

An ObjectDict instance *is a* regular dictionary via class inheritance. See `ObjectDict(dict)`

The `__getattr__` magic function allows for the definition of dot-notation access for any object. And it simply calls normal dictionary access here

Similarly, `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` allows setting and deleting (using Python's `del` expression) values from dot-notation. However, to set nested values, you need the value of the first key to also be an ObjectDict