# Overloading operators using __getattr__ in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to overload several operators at once using the `__getattr__` function. In my code, if I call `foo.__add__(other)` it works as expected, but when I try `foo + bar`, it does not. Here is a minimal example:

```
class Foo():
    
    
    def add(self, other):
        return 1 + other
    
    def sub(self, other):
        return 1 - other
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
                
        stripped = name.strip('_')
        if stripped in {'sub', 'add'}:
            return getattr(self, stripped)
        else:
            return
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    
    bar = Foo()
    
    print(bar.__add__(1)) # works
    print(bar + 1) # doesn't work
```

I realize that it would be easier in this example to just define `__add__` and `__sub__`, but that  is not an option in my case.

Also, as a small side question, if I replace the line:

```
if stripped in {'sub', 'add'}:
```

with

```
if hasattr(self, name):
```

the code works, but then my iPython kernel crashes. Why does this happen and how could I prevent it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but cannot prove at the moment, that the discrepancy between `bar.__add__(1)` and `bar + 1` is because the latter behavior invokes the behavior in the method `__add__()` directly, without actually accessing it the usual way. I think this is something that the interpreter does for _most_ builtins - at least in cpython, other implementations might do differently.

Comment: "if I replace the line ... the code works, but then my iPython kernel crashes" - that replacement will not make anything work. You must have misinterpreted what you saw.

Comment: Also, Python bypasses normal attribute lookup for operations like this, so no possible `__getattr__` implementation will achieve your goal. Just implement `__add__` and `__sub__`.

Comment: I also think (but can't prove) that vital operations like addition/subtraction circumvent the `__getattr__` machinery, so your `__getattr__` isn't being called by `bar + 1`

Comment: The reason why I don't want to implement `__add__` and `__sub__` is that I want to do this for a whole bunch of operators and I would like to avoid the redundant code. But I guess that this is the way to go...

Comment: Also to clarify the line "if I replace the line ... the code works, but then my iPython kernel crashes", I thought the code ran the same way as for `if stripped in {'sub', 'add'}:`, but didn't notice the infinite recursion it was in.

Comment: Is `1`-instead-of-`self` the trick you want to generalize for all transformation ? Which group's properties would you like your object to exhibit ? e.g. do you want your transformations to be commutative ? These are the questions that come to my mind when reading your post. Your wish to avoid redundant code makes indeed total sense.

Comment: The example I show here is just a toy example. My actual problem is that I want to write a wrapper class W to the class C. If W doesn't implement a method, the method of C should be used but the result converted to W if possible. I got this to work for non-magic methods with `__getattr__`, but would like it to work on operators as well. But in the mean-time I've stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057669/how-can-i-intercept-calls-to-pythons-magic-methods-in-new-style-classes/9059858#9059858) which should solve my problems :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because python operators use an optimization to look up the function implementing the operator. The following lines are roughly equivalent:

```
foo + 1
type(foo).__add__(foo, 1)
```

Operators are found specifically on the class object only, never on the instance.

`bar.__add__(1)` calls `__getattr__` to find the missing attribute on `bar`. This works because it bypasses normal operator lookup procedures.

`bar + 1` calls `Foo.__add__(bar, 1)` followed by `int.__radd(1, bar)`. The first attribute lookup fails, and the second option raises `TypeError`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this difference. Do you see a different way to go around this?

Comment: @drmaettu. You could try playing games with your metaclass. That would let you charge the way lookup works on the class object maybe. Depends on what you're really trying to do. I don't see the point of what you're trying to accomplish here, given that python already has a pretty solid inheritance mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, here's probably how to go about this (for reference):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057669/how-can-i-intercept-calls-to-pythons-magic-methods-in-new-style-classes/9059858#9059858

Comment: @drmaettu. I'm glad you were able to find that. Hopefully it provides the workaround you need, or convinces you not to do it.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, as a small side question, if I replace the line: [...]

[`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) calls [`__getattr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295678/understanding-the-difference-between-getattr-and-getattribute#:%7E:text=Use%20of%20__getattr__,what%20to%20do%20with%20it.) under the hood. Which explains what you saw when doing `if hasattr(self, name):`, you actually enter an infinite recursion since you have overwritten `__getattr__`.

See for yourself

```
class O:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print('yooo')
        return super().__getattr__(attr)
        #      self.__getattr__(attr) -> RecursionError
```

```
>>> hasattr(O(), 'ya')
yooo
False
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a semi-satisfying work-around that does not involve meta-classes:

```
class Foo():
    
    def add(self, other):
        return 1 + other
    
    def sub(self, other):
        return 1 - other

# Add operators to the type object
def get_operator(name):
    return getattr(Foo, name.strip('_'))

for op in ['__add__', '__sub__']:
    setattr(Foo, op, get_operator(op))

    
if __name__=='__main__':
    
    bar = Foo()
    
    print(bar + 2)
    print(bar - 2)
```