# Python - Proper way of serially reassign/update class members

Tags: python, numpy

I have a class whose members are lists of numbers built by accumulating values from experimental data, like

```
 class MyClass:
     def __init__(self):
          container1 = []
          container2 = []
            ...

     def accumulate_from_dataset(self,dataset):
          for entry in dataset:
               container1.append( foo (entry) )
               container2.append( bar (entry) )
                  ...


     def process_accumulated_data(self):   
           '''called when all the data is gathered
           '''
           process1(container1)
           process2(container2)
             ...
```

---

**Issue:** it would be beneficial if I could convert all the lists into numpy arrays.

---

**what I tried:** the simple conversion

```
    self.container1 = np.array(self.container1)
```

works. Although, if I would like to consider "more fields in one shot", like

```
     lists_to_convert = [self.container1, self.container2, ...]

     def converter(lists_to_convert):
          for list in lists_to_convert:
               list = np.array(list)
```

there is not any effective change since the references to the class members are passed by value.

---

I am thus wondering if there is a smart approach/workaround to handle the whole conversion process.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do this because as you say python passes "by-reference-by-value"

You could add a `to_numpy` method in your class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        container1 = []
        container2 = []
        ...
def to_numpy(self,container):
    list = self.__getattr__(container)
    self.__setattr__(container,np.array(list))
        ...
```

And then do something like:

```
object = MyClass()

lists_to_convert = ["container1", "container2" ...]

def converter(lists_to_convert):
    for list in lists_to_convert:
        object.to_numpy(list)
```

But it's not very pretty and this sort of code would normally make me take a step back and think about my design.

Comment: I guess some sort of `getattr` is missing though. `np.array(container)` being `container` a string can't work. isn't it?

Comment: Don't call `__those_hidden__` functions, use `getattr` and `setattr` builtins

Comment: @JakubM thanks for the comment, I think I agree with you but in your answer could you expand on why the builtins are particularly preferable to the hidden functions?

Comment: That's why you have those builtins built in for :) This post will give you a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944625/what-is-the-relationship-between-getattr-and-getattr

Answer (score 2):

From [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/Pragmatic%20Quick%20Reference.htm):

> Ask yourself: "Does it have to be done this way? Does it have to be done at all?

Maybe you should rethink your data structure? Maybe some dictionary or a simple list of lists would be easier to handle?

Note that in the example presented, `container1` and `container2` are just transformations on the initial `dataset`. It looks like a good place for list comprehension:

```
foo_data = [foo(d) for d in dataset]
# or even
foo_data = map(foo, dataset)
# or generator version
foo_data_iter = (foo(d) for d in dataset)
```

If you *really* want to operate on the instance variables as in the example, have a look at `getattr` and `hasattr` built-in functions

Comment: You are definitely right. It has been a design error. Now the class and the processing methods are unpleasantly large to change direction, though.

Comment: Abandon the ship! The code direction cannot be changed and it is heading for a sure maintenance disaster! :)