# Importing identically named methods

Tags: python, python-import

So I have two separate Python packages that I'm importing into my Python script for Raspberry Pi. In this case as;

```
from rflib import*
from Rpi.GPIO import*
```

However, both packages have their own seperate method `cleanup(self)`

So, at the end of the script when I use the command
`cleanup()`, how do I a) know which package the method is coming from (they both do utterly different things b) control which one is run?

I've looked into similarly named [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482427/two-classes-with-a-structurally-identical-method-but-one-differently-named-varia), but which seem to deal with inheritance overloading rather than package imports

Comment: Simple, don't use `from module import *`, import the module itself and use the attributes.

Comment: And the last import wins, so `Rpi.GPIO.cleanup()`  in this case. You can't reach the other, because the name is re-bound, so the old `cleanup = rflib.cleanup` is gone.

Comment: Okay - but assuming you have done `import*` - which method is run? The first to be imported?

Comment: always try to be specific import . from module import function .. other way around you can do import module as "any_name"

Comment: Sorry didnt see your second answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from <module> import *` takes all names in a module (those that don't start with a `_` or everything listed in `<module>.__all__` and assigns those names as globals in your current module.

If two modules define the same name, that means that the last one imported this way wins; `cleanup = rflib.cleanup` is replaced by `cleanup = Rpi.GPIO.cleanup` with the second `from Rpi.GPIO import *` statement.

You generally want to *avoid* using `from <module> import *`. Import specific names, or just the module itself.

In this case, you can do:

```
from rflib import cleanup as rflib_cleanup
from Rpi.GPIO import cleanup as rpigpio_cleanup
```

which would bind those two functions as *different* names.

Or you could just import the modules:

```
import rflib
from Rpi import GPIO
```

which gives you only the `rflib` and `GPIO` names, each a reference to the module object, so now you can reference each of the `cleanup` functions as attributes on those modules:

```
rflib.cleanup()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

If you need to use a lot of names from either module, the latter style is preferred because that limits the number of imports you need to do, keeps your namespace clean and un-cluttered, and gives you more context whereever those names are used in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to use `*` with `import`. You should be doing something like:

```
import rflib
from Rpi import GPIO

# Clean Up 1
rflib.cleanup

#Clean Up 2
GPIO.cleanup()
```

---

*Additional pice of information:*

In case your files/objects are of same name, in that case you should use `as` with `import`. For example:

```
   from file1 import utils as file1_utils
   from file2 import utils as file2_utils

   file1_utils.my_func()
   file2_utils.my_func()
```